# How do I make an API query and display the Json result?

Tags: json, wordpress, api, get

I'm using an API to receive information from a server. I'm authorising using a token. I can query using curl or various api testers online. But now I'm trying to learn how to implement (and request) the results in practice.

I'd like to query, parse and display the json result on a web page (preferably a Wordpress site).

So I need to make a get request, authorise myself using my token, and receive the result and then display it in a nice way.

How do I do that?

Comment: Do you want to make the request to the API from a WordPress site? If not, what language or framework are you planning to use?

Comment: I do want to make the request to the API from a WordPress site.

Answer (score 1):

This is a vague question, not really sure if you are making requests from just one side but you have 2 options, albeit one being better than the other.

You can create add multiple functions inside your themes function.php file to extend its capabilities but again these are limited to only the theme you are using.

I would recommend that you build a plugin, this will give you the flexibility to use both JS and PHP to do whatever you need to do. With this method you can create a shortcode to display the results from your API query.

You will need to learn to use the Wordpress function wp_remote_get() to perform external API calls.

Here is a tutorial with more information:

[Create Plugin and Create External API Calls](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-look-at-the-wordpress-http-api-a-practical-example-of-wp_remote_get--wp-32109)

[Parse JSON from Remote API](https://pippinsplugins.com/using-wp_remote_get-to-parse-json-from-remote-apis/)

Hope this helps

Comment: Great answer. I think those two links do answer my question. I'll give it a try. Thanks.